# "Unable to obtain OAuth Token for Push" after upgrading MFP 8 from Tomcat 7 to 8.5

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, tomcat8, mobilefirst-server

I am upgrading my MFP 8 server from Tomcat 7 to 8.5 (to solve a different problem). I have installed Tomcat 8.5.24 from an official gzip file, copied the configuration and web applications and started the server. I can log on to the console, however, it keeps saying mfp environment is not initalized. The error log says the following:

```
20-Dec-2017 20:44:18.687 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-11] com.ibm.mfp.admin.util.PushServiceUtil.getOAuthToken Obtaining oAuth token failed with the following response: net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.24</h3></body></html>
20-Dec-2017 20:44:18.689 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-11] com.ibm.mfp.admin.util.PushServiceUtil.getOAuthToken Unable to obtain OAuth Token for Push
```

I found an article regarding this very issue (https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/09/06/confidential-client-configuration-for-mobilefirst-topologies/), double-checked the URLs concerned, but they are both good:

```
<Environment name="mfp.admin.authorization.server.url" value="http://localhost:8080/mfp" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
<Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.server.url" value="http://localhost:8080/mfp/api" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

I haven't touched these settings. Moreover, switching back to Tomcat 7 with exact same settings starts MFP with no problems. Can it have anything to do with any change in addressing of JNDI entries in Tomcat 8.5 (e.g. requiring a prefix or anything)? These are both contained in their respective contexts (`<Context docBase="mfpadmin" path="/mfpadmin">` and `<Context docBase="imfpush" path="/imfpush">`).

Looking forward to any suggestions.

UPDATE.

- MFP 8.0.0.00-20170710-1834
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11). Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
- I presume Push Service was installed automatically. Below is the exact JNDI configuration.

  ```
    <Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.server.url" value="http://localhost:8080/mfp/api" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.client.id" value="Push_Default" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.client.secret" value="XXXXXXX" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.push.services.ext.security" value="com.ibm.mfp.push.server.security.plugin.OAuthSecurityPlugin" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.push.db.type" value="DB" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>

    <Environment name="mfp.admin.push.url" value="http://localhost:8080/imfpush" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.admin.authorization.server.url" value="http://localhost:8080/mfp" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.client.id" value="Push_Default" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.client.secret" value="t2SWy9sXaRfv" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.admin.authorization.client.id" value="Admin_Default" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.admin.authorization.client.secret" value="XXXXXXXXXX" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.topology.platform" value="Tomcat" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.topology.clustermode" value="Standalone" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.config.service.password" value="XXXXXXXXX" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
    <Environment name="mfp.config.service.user" value="configUser_mfpadmin" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
  ```

Comment: did you try using https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/index.html ?

Comment: where exactly in the documentation do you suggest that I should look? I think this problem is MFP-related and not specifically Tomcat-related. JNDI is purely my own suggestion. If someone confirms that this is the right direction, I would surely look into docs in more detail.

Comment: Did you try using Latest Tomcat 8 ? and is the issue occuring in Latest Tomcat 8 also / is it specific to Tomcat 8.5 ?